# Accessing controller $scope in callback method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ros

Heyho!

I am using ROS (Robot Operating System) in combination with roslib.js and angular.js.

A method is calling a service, this is done via network and takes some time. The best way would be, that this call is blocking. But it isn’t. The wanted data is received from the callback, but it is not possible to copy the data somewhere else to the controller.

In my opinion it is a problem of Scopes. But I already implemented a Factory for receiving the data and tried a dirty hack with $rootScope but nothing worked...

Here is some descriptive code:

**View**:

Here a ng-repeat listens to the variable *list* in the controller rosCtrl

**JS**:

```
Controller rosController
  var rosCtrl = this;
  rosCtrl.list = [];

  this.receiveData = function(){
    callService(input, function(result){
      ..
      .. some logging for debugging ..
      rosCtrl.list.push({name: "a", type: 1});
    }
  }
```

The data is successfully received and with other methods I can add items to the list and the view is updated. So there isn’t any problem in the mechanism.

Hope I could give you an understanding of the problem. If not, please let me know, so I will try to explain it more detailed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is list a scope variable? if no, which is the line where you atttempted to assign new value to a scope variable? If the assignment is performed outside angular context, did you try to get hold of $scope in context and call a $scope.$apply() after assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for both of your answers. I tried your ideas, but they didn’t work either. Meanwhile I found the problem: Another programmer added two times the same controller nested in another controller and that's why the content of the list was empty all the time. Sometimes life is that easy..... Gnarf....

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jPH4d5RiinxOGuxMjSRr?p=preview

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('rosController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = ['World'];

    $scope.sayHello = function() {

      setTimeout(function callService(){
        $scope.list.push('Another '+Math.random().toString().split('.')[1]);
      },100);
    }
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```